# x86: register operation as memory content and memory address?

Tags: x86, cpu-registers

register ---> memory address --> memory content

memory address --> memory content

is the above model correct??

and, if it is can you suggest if i am thinking it right or not??

movl %eax, %ebx --> it moves memory address of eax to ebx which results in content moving as well??

movl (%eax),%ebx --> it just moves content and doesnot touch address??

movl value, %eax --> moves memory address of value  to %eax (and content as well i.e. eax has new memory content)

movl %eax, val ---> val has new memory address and content as well(both of %eax)

movl $val, %eax ---> val is a content which is moved to content of %eax(address doesnt change)

movl %eax, $val ---> ?????

movl (%eax), val ---> val has just the new memory content

mov (%eax), $val ---> error?

mov $val, (%eax) ---> error?

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax

Comment: `%eax` and `%ebx` do not *have* a memory address, they are registers and can merely *contain* memory addresses.

Comment: Most of these do not make sense. Note that in AT&T (Gnu) syntax, the order of destination and source is reversed WRT Intel syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movl %eax, %ebx`  --> moves the *content* of register `%eax` into register `%ebx`. It is irrelevant what `%eax` contains.

`movl (%eax),%ebx` --> moves the content of the *memory address* contained in `%eax` into register `%ebx`

`movl value, %eax` --> moves content of *memory address `value`* into register `%eax`.

`movl %eax, val`   --> moves content of register `%eax` to *memory address `val`*

`movl $val, %eax`  --> moves the *constant `$val`* into the register `%eax`

`movl %eax, $val` --> **impossible**. You cannot move something into a constant value.

`movl (%eax), val` --> **impossible**. You must use a register as intermediate:

```
movl (%eax),%eax
movl %eax,val    ; or use another intermediate register than %eax
```

`mov (%eax), $val` --> i**mpossible**. You cannot move something into a constant value.

`mov $val, (%eax)` --> move *constant value `$val`* into *memory address* contained in `%eax`.

Comment: %eax --> 0x100   and 0x100: 0x123

%ebx --> 0x212    and 0x212:: 0x456

then movl %eax, %ebx will result in:
%ebx --> 0x100 ... is it correct??

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of data `%eax` contains. It can be an address, an integer, or whatever, anytime, `movl %eax,%ebx` simply copies the value in `%eax` to `%ebx`. So if `%eax` is `0x100`, then `%ebx` will become `0x100` too.